# Safari's favorites bar - getting images instead of text labels, especially via emojis

Tags: safari, bookmarks, emoji

The Safari favorites bar seems to allow only text labels on the favorites bar. I would like to replace those with something like a favicon. This is apparently not directly supported at this time.

Please note: there are a set of similar issues with many web pages giving answers. This question is not about those issues. Here is a list of similar issues, which are already well explained:

1. Dealing with favicons in the bookmarks bar that appears at the left of the browser window when enabled.
2. Dealing with favicons in the favorites page.
3. Dealing with favicons on the tabs.
4. Dealing with icons of the above types that disappear.
5. Dealing with websites that show a generic images of either a "world" or a capital letter depending upon context.

While those are legitimate issues, there are many workarounds discussed already. This question is about the favorites bar, not the bookmarks bar nor the favorites page, nor the tabs. For context, here is a screen shot of my current favorites bar:

[image: favorites bar]

You will notice that most of the tags are text. I have not been able to find anything for current versions of Safari that allow images instead. It seems older versions of Safari allowed a right-click on the favorites bar and then giving the choice to show text, image or both. But now the only choice on the context menu is "New Folder".

You will also notice that I have put three images on the favorites bar in the screen shot. This is accomplished by putting into the text field an emoji.

Using an emoji gives an interesting workaround, but is limited by availability of emojis, which do not generally correspond to website logos.

An obvious next step would be to have a tool that can create an emoji from a favicon. In searching for that I find that there are a plethora of tools that can create a favicon from an emoji. But apparently the tool for the reverse conversion are rare. It might even be that such a conversion is not a practical goal.

There could be two simple answers to this questions then:

1. An answer that shows the native method for having the favorites bar display images;
2. An answer that links to a tool that can convert favicons to emojis.